# Getting error 500 with spring cloud gateway with azure ad,oauth2 client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, cloud, api-gateway

I have create two services one is microservices  and other is api gateways service.
I am using azure Ad with oauth2 for authentication.
The issue I am facing is particular to my company environments.
The same code is working fine with my personal pc and personal account.

http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure?code=codefromazure

I cannot share my code here. I have attached screen shot.
Spring is only provide me the error.
I am not getting if it is due to some proxy.[image].
I have same credential working fine with oauth2.
The only difference here I am using spring boot 3.1.5 version.

please help me out I am stuck with this from last 1 week.

Comment: Please dont post screenshot but feel free to post the error message (as text).

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, it is a timeout issue so probably some firewall rules preventing the connection ro something ?

Comment: The something he can't access is `login.microsoftonline.com`. Sure that OAuth2 won't work if users can't access the authorization server...

Comment: but I am getting code in url  from azure.@ch4mp

url- http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure?code=CodeFromAzure

Comment: This is the how it should work.
User initiates login and gets redirected to Azure AD.
After successful login, Azure AD issues an authorization code to the client application.
The client application exchanges this code for an access token and a refresh token.

Comment: This is how it should work
User initiates login and gets redirected to Azure AD.

After successful login, Azure AD issues an authorization code to the client application.

The client application exchanges this code for an access token and a refresh token.
But after second step my spring application not able to perform third and final step.
It also showing in error.
It should post this URL with code it has received from azure -> https://login.microsoftonline.com/2d03d1ef-904a-4f39-865e-efc6112a3031/oauth2/v2.0/token.
but it is not able to complete it.